# Assume that $10$ students were randomly selected from this class. Find the probability that $2$ are $1$st year and $5$ are $3$rd year.

Tags: probability

> In a large university statistics class, it is known that $10\%$ are $1$st year, $25\%$ are $2$nd year, $40\%$ are $3$rd year, and $25\%$ are $4$th and special student. Assume that $10$ students were randomly selected from this class. Find the probability that $2$ are $1$st year and $5$ are $3$rd year.

I'm not sure how to start with this problem. I thought about using Hypergeometric but I don't have a sample size. This leaves Poisson I guess but I don't have a mean.

Comment: Please investigate 'multinomial distribution'. If this were a community college with only 1st yr students (60%) and 2nd yr (40%), could you use binomial distribution to figure out the probability that 3 of five students chosen are first year? (I think you are correct to discard hypergeometric and Poisson.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sample size, I think you mean population size. The sample size is $10$.

I think the problem means to say that $2$ are 1st year, $5$ are 3rd, and $3$ are other.
By "large" I think you can take that to mean that these are the chances exactly.

Then the quick way to solve this is to recognize that you are dealing with a multinomial distribution, if you covered that (yet). Hence, we have
$$\binom{10}{2,5,3} (.10)^2(.4)^5(.5)^3.$$

Alternatively, you need to get $2$ 1sts, $5$ 3rds, $3$ others. But it this does not account for the order. You need to unorder the 1st $\binom{10}{2}$, unorder the 3rds, $\binom{8}{5}$, and unorder the others, $\binom{3}{3}$. Hence
$$\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{5}\binom{3}{3} (.10)^2(.4)^5(.5)^3= \binom{10}{2,5,3} (.10)^2(.4)^5(.5)^3.$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the chance of a particular sequence happening. Let's look at the sequence of getting (1st year, 1st year, 3rd year, 3rd year, 3rd year, 3rd year, 3rd year) in this order. Then, it is easy to see that the probability of this happening is
$$
\frac{1}{10}\times \frac{1}{10}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}
$$
Similarly a sequence of getting (1st year, 3rd year, 1st year, 3rd year, 3rd year, 3rd year, 3rd year) is
$$
\frac{1}{10}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{1}{10}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}\times \frac{2}{5}
$$
which is equal to the probability of the first sequence. The idea here is that any such sequence that results in the same distribution of 1st year and 3rd year students have the same chance.

Now, if you are able to find out the distinct number of such sequences, then you can sum over their probabilities to get the total chance of getting what you need.

So the problem of how many such sequences can be resolved in the following way. You have 7 slots. You have 2 1st year and 5 3rd year students. How do you place them? You would notice that 7 for the first one, 6 for the second one etc. However, 2 1st year students are identically regarded, thus you would need to divide it by 2. Moreover, 5 of those are identical as 3rd year students each of which was regarded as distinct. So the total number is also inflated $5!$ times. Thus the total number of such sequences is 
$$
\frac{7!}{5!2!} = {7 \choose 5}.
$$ 
Thus, you have
$$
{7 \choose 5} \left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2
$$
probability of such an event.

Comment: I think you have 10 slots, where 3 can be anything.